# Multivariate Gaussian distribution

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution, gaussian-process

I was going through Andrew Ng's Machine learning course and was a bit confused about the difference between Gaussian distribution and multivariate Gaussian distribution. As per my understanding multivariate Gaussian distribution is for models where we have multiple features like x1,x2...xn but the same thing could be done for original model

[image]

I know I am totally confused here.

Comment: I am not sure of what you are asking. Are the variables on the left normal? If so, it seems they are independent. What does their product represent, is it a joint probability?

Answer (score 2):

[image][image]The multivariate Gaussian reflects correlation between the random variables.
Imagine fitting data to a line $y=mx+b$ but there is scatter in the data.
If you were to randomly pick and x-value and independently pick a y-value, chances are it would not lie on the fit line.
Using a multivariate distribution $F(x,y)$ which is not simply $G(x)H(y)$ will capture the correlation between x and y.